# Itemize Environment: Change only size of the bullet not the text

Tags: environments, itemize, bullets

I would like to change only the size of the bullet not the text of item as mentioned in the question. I tried following approach but it changes the bullet size as well as text size. Thanks in advance for your help.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  {\large
   \begin{itemize} 
    \item Item 1 
    \item Item 2 
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
   \end{itemize}  
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bigger or smaller?

Comment: @egreg: I would like to see for `\large` size.

Comment: The reason why `{\large...}` doesn't work (well, it works, but it changes anything) is that the scope of `\large` is restricted to the `itemize` environment, but since there is no other font change (usually) this has an effect on all typesetting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The optional argument of `enumitem` can be used with `label={\large\textbullet}`, but this will not produce the best result always, perhaps, tiny bullets may have to be raised a little bit.

As can be seen, the font size of the normal text isn't changed.

There's the `font=...` option as well, meant for the label font (which can be 'any' command, from font size change to complete font shape change)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

{ Tiny bullets: \tiny \textbullet}
\begin{itemize}[label={\tiny\raisebox{1ex}{\textbullet}}]
\item Item 1 
\item Item 2 
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}  

{Normally sized bullets: \textbullet}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1 
\item Item 2 
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}  

{Large bullets: \Large \textbullet}
\begin{itemize}[label={\large\textbullet}]
\item Item 1 
\item Item 2 
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}  
\end{document}
```

[image]